# Expressjs : when to use json.parse when receiving data from res.json

Tags: jquery, json, express

I am calling an express api from my html file. The api returns the following code :

```
res.json([{
  task: "Exercise",
  desc: "running"
},{
  task: "Exercise2",
  desc: "running2"
},{
  task: "Exercise3",
  desc: "running3"
}]);
```

I am calling the above API using jQuery's `$.get`:

```
$.get(url, {}, function(response) {
  var responseArray = JSON.parse(response); //this line is not needed
});
```

I was under the impression I need to do `JSON.parse` on the response. But it is not needed. I was thinking `res.json` will call the `stringify()` function to turn the array into JSON. Obviously, my understanding has some holes. Could some one please explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to parse the response manually as jQuery's default setting for the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter on AJAX requests is 'best guess'. This means that when a response is received jQuery will determine it's format from the content type header.

In your case this header would appear to be `application/json`, hence jQuery internally deserialises the JSON string for you and provides the resulting object to your handler function within the `response` argument.

Comment: When i inspect the response in devtools it is shown as an array, not string :  [{"task":"Exercise","desc":"running"},{"task":"Exercise2","desc":"running2"},{"task":"Exercise3","desc":"running3"}]

Comment: Why is this?Shouldn't the data received be string, which is then converted to an object by jquery ?

Comment: ... I literally just explained what is happening and why in the answer above

Comment: This is my understanding of what you said : "the res.json() will convert convert the array into json string and send to client .There , the jquery will  guess its data type to be json and convert it back to array". What I am trying to say is, if I inspect the data received (using the network tab in chrome devtools) , shouldn't the data be json string ? I am seeing an object instead of a string.

Comment: The response will 100% be a string - it's all HTTP can transfer. If you're seeing an array or object it's because network tools itself has also determined the response type and deserialised it

Answer (score 0):

Well, its easy to explain. [jQuery documentation says](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

> dataType
>   Type: String
>   The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

That call by default *intelligently* guesses JSON.